# How to redirect to a subdomain using lvh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the url like this `orgname.lvh.me:3000` it's working fine, and well. Now I need to redirect to this url after a specific action. How do I do this

I have tried this

```
 root_path(subdomain: "orgname")
```

But this is simply going to localhost:3000. But instead I want to redirect to the url like

```
orgname.lvh.me:3000
```

Update:

I have tried this string interpolation

```
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    byebug
    "#{resource.name}.lvh.me:3000"
    #TODO  redirect to a subdomain resource.name is giving the organization name 
  end
```

I ended up like this 
[image: like another app]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the url as redirect.

```
redirect_to 'http://orgname.lvh.me:3000'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I tried a bunch of different methods, but turns out is really simple.
Instead of using root_path, use root_url, overriding the devise method after_sign_in_path_for like this.

```
#application_controller.rb 

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  root_url(subdomain: "orgname")
end
```

I hope it helped you.